# its about the javascript programming

Tags: javascript

I want to develop a website which takes a voice or speech input from the user.

example:
if a user says that he wants to login so he should be redirected to the login page .
Note:
the input should be in the form of speech i.e the user shoulf speak "i want to login"

so now there a problem exist i dont know how to do it

i searched for it online but there is a api called as WEB SPEECH API  but i am not understanding how to use it

so are there any related answers to that ?

i would appreciate if the answers are related using the above API .
 or any other related suggestions
 thank you

Comment: What specifically are you not understanding? If the answer is "most" or "all of it", I would suggest looking for a video tutorial to walk you through getting started. It is probably best to start with a tutorial example when learning something new if it doesn't make sense right away.

Comment: are you having any tutorials for it?

Comment: any link to the tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to the last comment on your question, here are a few tutorials that you can try. The first three are text and the last one is a video tutorial. I searched "web speech api tutorial" in google to find these. There were many more, so if these do not suit you then try some of the others.

1. [Introduction to web speech api](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API)
2. [Documentation and examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API)
3. [Hands on tutorial for web speech api](https://speechlogger.appspot.com/developers/)
4. [Demo and example for web speech api](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyu0W-yCUAM)